# when I use yum install python-devel -y in centos8 system

Tags: yum, centos8

Prompt me for the following error

No match for argument: python-devel
[image]

Comment: please don't post screenshots but actual text.

Answer (score 13):

`python2.7` is completely obsolete by now. You should work with `python3`. Hence you could install:

```
dnf install python3-devel -y
```

(`dnf` is the replacement for `yum` on centos8. `yum` is still available but just an alias for `dnf`)

Comment: For specific python version, say for python3.8 then `dnf install python38-devel -y`

Comment: Maybe also u need to update system repos before: `yum update -y && yum install -y epel-release && yum install -y dnf-plugins-core && yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools`